# How to sync removed branches?

Tags: git

I have branches like "main" and "refactoring". I made the changes I needed in "refactoring" and created a pull request in "main" and accepted it. Now the "refactoring" branch gets in the way. I removed it from the GitHub interface. How can I sync locally now? So that the "refactoring" branch does not appear on the local repository?
Until this day, I would just delete the "refactoring" branch locally and that's it. But I feel that this is wrong and decided to find out how to do it right.
How do I keep my local branches in sync with branches in a remote repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Git does not automatically prune local branches. You can use `git fetch -p` to prune local *tracking* branches like `remotes/origin/refactoring`, but it won't delete the plain `refactoring` branch for you. If Git were to delete branches whose upstream refs had disappeared there would be a risk of data loss. You don't want your local data disappearing because something happened on the remote.

Therefore, deleting the branch manually is appropriate:

```
$ git fetch
<see a message that the remote branch 'refactoring' has been deleted>

$ git branch -d refactoring
```

If accepting the PR involved squashing commits or otherwise rewriting the commit history then you'll need to force delete:

```
$ git branch -D refactoring
```

(Note that while I understand Git's behavior I don't love it. I'm not defending it, merely explaining it.)

Comment: Yes, this is sort of the same thing I was complaining about in my now deleted https://stackoverflow.com/q/71086710/341994. Except my point there was that you have to say `-D` and not just `-d`. I suspect the OP will have to do the same; you might want to change your answer accordingly.

Comment: @matt Done, I added a note about `-D`. Note that `-d` should work if the merge strategy is fast forwarding or creating a merge commit. I think it's only squashing that requires it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It seems to me that deleting local branches can indeed be dangerous, but you can only delete those that do not have commits ahead of the main branch. That is, if "refactoring" is not ahead of "main", and the "refactoring" branch has deleted on the remote repository, then deleting "refactoring" is safe. Do you think there are utilities or plugins for IDE (VSCode) to implement such cleaning? I have more than 30 branches in another project, although 2-3 are used. There also git-flow is not respected.

Comment: That's a good point. It could do `branch -d` automatically. It's only `-D` that would be dangerous.

Comment: I don't know about VSCode plugins. I never took to using its Git extensions; I stick to the CLI.